# How to enforce mapped type to have all of the keys in a string literal

Tags: typescript

Given the following list:

```js
const list = ["A", "B", "C"] as const;
type List = typeof list[number];
```

I have a map that must have all of the possible keys of `list`:

```js
const mapping: Record<List, unknown> = {
  A: true,
  B: 2,
  C: "three"
};
```

Just like I could enforce `mapping` to map over `List`, I would like to do the same for a type. Something like this (I'm aware it's an invalid syntax):

```js
type MappedList: Record<List, unknown> = {
  A: boolean,
  B: number,
  C: string
}
```

My main goal is to prevent a situation when I add a new cell into `list` and forget to add it to `MappedList`.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gIgIKYDQyYBC+hAwpgLowCGEMokUA3AFBQCeADgKYwAySKAGkeHVDE68QAM3hD0YAK4BbAEY8ATpTatGyFTS5cEYAOYAuGACUeoTQBMAPIOiiOBJWADWYEAHcwAD4JAG9WGBhsKyhNJR48CJgiKwAmRMiyK0woAAtNHh58VgBfXSk+AFkjXgdXKCtbe2d6908fP0CQtHDI6Jg1EBA4HhowNkiUmGV1LQmYLJhoTVMzNhKgA)

Comment: Is it strictly necessary for you to have a list of required keys in an array? May I propose a solution where the source-of-truth value is an object rather than an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a utility that would require generics to match:

```js
type AssertKeysEqual<
  T1 extends Record<keyof T2, any>,
  T2 extends Record<keyof T1, any>
> = T2


const list = ["A", "B", "C"] as const;
type ListKey = typeof list[number];

const mapping: Record<ListKey, unknown> = {
  A: true,
  B: 2,
  C: "three",
};

type MappedList = AssertKeysEqual<Record<ListKey, unknown>, {
  A: boolean;
  B: number;
  C: string;
}>
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznCAnYBpCI4FECOBXAQwBsAeAKCigBUBGKCAD2AgDsATOKAJQgGMB7JGxIBrDPwBm1AEwAaKARYgAfLIoz6TVh259BwsSEnUa8xSrLKoAXhlkyAlnGBQiAS2c2oAbQBEMX3lfACFAqF8AYV8AXQVOR2cAbjJQSCgAGQ80DC9UiGN3Z28WPABbACNkaOSHficXUoIwMDcWAHMALl0BIRJM53QQeTwWERZ%20AHcWK1sAb3UYLuAkPAg1SmCuuXUIrt9gAAskCAhAsgBfGryoAFkmyDZ%20l1t4RBRB7HxiEh4e4SfBsNRuMpqooPNKIsoOV%20PwiBBFMkNl0ShVkEioLsoM4kK02slzsp7Nc7s0II8slgkEgvK9kNlMLhCKRfvo%20llAVARmNJtN5BDYF0YXCESwMZsoKjKkgCUSUuBoKSHk8qUhpLSEPSPkzvqzegCMECeaD%20QshbD4Yj1BKpeidl0cXiMQARB3LJ0XIlAA)

Comment: I would replace `any` with `unknown` but it seems like a valid solution for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there is not such concept as type for type. However, you can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to create one type from another.

```js
const list = ["A", "B", "C"] as const;

type ListKey = typeof list[number];

// type MappedList = {
//     A: "property";
//     B: "property";
//     C: "property";
// }
type MappedList = {
  [Prop in ListKey]: 'property'
}
```

As far as I understood, you also need to assure that `A` is a `boolean`, `B` is a `number` and `C` is a `string`. In order to do it, you need create a map and conditional type:

```js
const list = ["A", "B", "C"] as const;

type ListKey = typeof list[number];

type TypeMap = {
  A: boolean,
  B: number,
  C: string
};

/**
 * If T is a subtype of TypeMap
 * and keyof T extends keyof TypeMap
 */
type BuildMappedList<T> = T extends TypeMap ? keyof T extends keyof TypeMap ? T : never : never;

/**
 * Ok
 */
type MappedList = BuildMappedList<{
  A: true,
  B: 2,
  C: "three",
}>

/**
 * Never
 */
type MappedList2 = BuildMappedList<{
  A: true,
  B: 2,
  C: "three",
  D: [2] // because of extra D property
}>

/**
 * Never
 */
type MappedList3 = BuildMappedList<{
  B: 2,
  C: "three",
}> // because no A property

/**
 * Never
 */
type MappedList4 = BuildMappedList<{
  A: false,
  B: [2], // because B is not a number
  C: "three",
}>
```

[enter link description here](https://tsplay.dev/WvYLnm)

Comment: In generic entities, constraints for type parameters are _sort of_ "types for types", – could we utilize this idea?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky sure, we can. I just meant that there is no way to use `:` notation for type.

Comment: Although `MappedListX` would be considered as `never`, we won't really get any errors on this type, but rather on the code that depends on it, so it is partially ok. While it might be helpful to some others, the other answer fits my needs. Thanks!